# To show that a vector field $F (R^2)$ is conservative, is it sufficient to say that $(dQ/dx) - (dP/dy) = 0$?

Tags: greens-theorem

If i have a vector field

$$
F = (y,x)
$$
is it then possible to say that
$$
dQ/dx - dP/dy =0
$$
to be certain that F is conservative? Is this then related to Greens formula somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The vector field $F=(y,x)$ is the gradient of the function $(x,y) \to xy$, so it is conservative. In more fancy terms, the 1-form $f=y dx+x dy$ is exact since it holds $f=d(xy)$.
In general, it is not sufficient to check that $\partial_y F_x -\partial_x F_y=0$ the domain over which the field is defined should be simply connected, i.e. there should not be "holes" in it. The celebrated counterexample is $F=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$. Writing the associated 1-form: $\omega=F_x dx+F_y dy$ in polar coordinates gives $d\theta$ which is not exact, despite the poor notation, since $\int_{S^1} \omega=\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta=2\pi$.

Comment: I found this text "The valid statement is that if F is conservative, then its curl must be zero. Without additional conditions on the vector field, the converse may not be true, so we cannot conclude that F is conservative just from its curl being zero." 

If this is the case its not possible to determine if its conservative ?

Comment: @Joakim with additional conditions we can still determine if the vector field is conservative - for example if the domain on which it is defined is a star domain, (meaning there is one point $x_0$ in the domain for which the line segment from any $x$ to $x_0$ lies completely in the domain). Then a vector field with curl zero is conservative. So in general one would have to clearly state the domain on which we look at the vector field, because it is relevant to the question.